# What is the average age of my flesh and my bone?

Tags: cell-biology, senescence, bone-biology

A [study](http://www.nytimes.com/2005/08/02/science/your-body-is-younger-than-you-think.html?_r=0) reported in the New York Times on August 2, 2005, claims that the average age of all cells in a middle age human is 7-10 years. This was based on new techniques at the time that allowed for very precise measurements of carbon-14 in human DNA.

My question is partly regarding whether or not this claim has been confirmed, changed or improved upon in the 12-odd years since the original study.

Mainly however, my question is simply: What is the average age of the flesh, bone and body as a whole of a middle-aged human?